# error en método recursivo

Tags: c++, codeblocks

hola buenas me explicarían que falla en este simple método recursivo que estoy haciendo

```
*******************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool verificarIdentificacion(string[][1], int, string);


bool verificarIdentificacion(string matriz[][1], int contador, string identificacion){
    
    if(contador <3){
     
    if(matriz[contador][0] == identificacion){
        
        return true;
        
        }else{
        
        contador++;
        
        verificarIdentificacion(matriz,contador,identificacion);
        }
        
    }
    
    return false;
    
}


int main()
{
    string matriz[1][1] = {{"2","hola1"},{"4","hola2"}};
    int contador=0;
    
    
    
    
    if(verificarIdentificacion(matriz,contador, "4")){
        
        std::cout << "encontrada" << std::endl;
        
    }else{
        
        std::cout << "no encontrada" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

la idea es tener una matriz que  donde en la columna 0 siempre habra un identificador, entonces la idea es que por medio de un método recursivo, intento recorrer todas las filas evaluando siempre la columna 0 que es donde está el número, pero me tira error el metodo recursivo , sera que podrian ayudarme gracias.

el error es este

```
main.cpp: In function ‘bool verificarIdentificacion(std::string (*)[1], int, std::string)’:
main.cpp:25:44: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string’} to ‘std::string (*)[1]’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string (*)[1]’}
```

y este tambien

```
main.cpp:33:55: error: too many initializers for ‘std::string [1]’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string [1]’}
```

Comment: Que error te tira? Stackoverflow??

Comment: gracias ya lo escribi

Comment: La línea `bool verificarIdentificacion(string[1][1]int, string);` parece estar mal escrita y le falta una coma

Comment: ya arregle todo lo que me dijiste pero checalo ahora

Comment: me dice esto main.cpp:33:55: error: too many initializers for ‘std::string [1]’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string [1]’}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La siguiente declaración está mal y es redundante:

```
bool verificarIdentificacion(string[1][1]int, string);
```

Te falta una coma entre el primer y segundo parámetro.

---

Además, para pasar una variable como parámetro solo usas su nombre. En la línea:

```
verificarIdentificacion(matriz[1][1],contador, "4"){
```

Estás pasando el elemento en la posición 1, 1 de la matriz. Pero la función recibe una matriz.
Eso es lo que te indica el error.

Por cierto, al final va un `;` y no `{`. Así:

```
verificarIdentificacion(matriz, contador, "4");
```

En de la función recursiva también tienes problemas similares.

---

En cuanto al error `too many initializers`, se debe a que la matriz es de 1x1 pero la inicializas con más elementos de los necesarios.

Debería quedar así:

```
string matriz[1][1] = { "2" };
```

Sino agranda la matriz para que entren todos los elementos que necesites.

Comment: sigue marcando los errores si auque lo arregle

Comment: me marca este error

Comment: main.cpp:33:55: error: too many initializers for ‘std::string [1]’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string [1]’}

Comment: @Esther Con la edición que hiciste mi respuesta queda en el aire. Cuando edites las preguntas agrega información, no la borres o la cambies sustancialmente.

Comment: a ok no sabia perdón

Comment: sabes a que se pueda deber este error
main.cpp:33:55: error: too many initializers for ‘std::string [1]’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string [1]’}