# Error de inicialización de matriz en metodo recursivo

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Ya había echo la pregunta, pero alguien me ayudo en unos problemas pero como la el error persiste hago otra pregunta.

pasa que este código me arroja este error

> ```
> main.cpp:33:55: error: too many initializers for ‘std::string [1]’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string [1]’}
> ```

parece que es de inicialización pero no sé como arreglarlo.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool verificarIdentificacion(string[][1], int, string);


bool verificarIdentificacion(string matriz[][1], int contador, string identificacion){
    
    if(contador <3){
     
    if(matriz[contador][0] == identificacion){
        
        return true;
        
        }else{
        
        contador++;
        
        verificarIdentificacion(matriz,contador,identificacion);
        }
        
    }
    
    return false;
    
}


int main()
{
    string matriz[1][1] = {{"2","hola1"},{"4","hola2"}};
    int contador=0;
    
    
    
    
    if(verificarIdentificacion(matriz,contador, "4")){
        
        std::cout << "encontrada" << std::endl;
        
    }else{
        
        std::cout << "no encontrada" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fíjate, que cuando llamas recursivamente a verificarIdentificacion, no guardas el resultado, y después devuelve false... así que aunque compilara, devolvería siempre false, a no ser que lo encuentre a la primera.
Por cierto, entiendo que es un ejercicio... si ya han explicado los punteros, es muy probable que debas usarlos, repasa el tema "paso por referencia". Si no, pues repasa el tema "paso por valor".

Comment: si eso me di cuenta gracias,

Comment: el problema que no puedo resolver es el que menciono, apenas lo arregle ,arreglo eso que dices

Comment: El array és 2x2, así que cambia los todos los  [1] por [2]

Comment: En otra pregunta ya hablaste sobre ese error y [te respondí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/588079/169744).